# TLS connection ignoring assigned client certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, x509certificate, tls1.2

So I'm having some issues connecting out to a web service but only through my IIS hosted website. I have no problem accessing the web service through a browser (IE/Chrome) or through LinqPad. Looking at a network trace using system.diagnostics, it looks like my client certificate is being ignored even thought it is set (an exception is thrown if the certificate can't be found before the attempt at the connection so this is not the issue I think).

Considering the code is working fine from Linqpad and I can access the web service from browsers I'm wondering is this an IIS issue or maybe something to do with server updates ( Windows Server 2012 R2) ?

Here are some snippets from the network trace:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [3040] 
TlsStream#57420154::.ctor(host=***.**.**.***, #certs=0, 
checkCertificateRevocationList=False, sslProtocols=Default, Tls11, Tls12)

System.Net Information: 0 : [3040] 
SecureChannel#13120424::.ctor(hostname=***.**.**.***, 
#clientCertificates=0, encryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
System.Net Information: 0 : [3040] SecureChannel#13120424 - Left with 0 
client certificates to choose from.

System.Net Error: 0 : [5104] Exception in HttpWebRequest#13834363:: - The 
request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5104] Entering 
HttpWebRequest#13834363::EndGetResponse()
System.Net Error: 0 : [5104] Exception in 
HttpWebRequest#13834363::EndGetResponse - The request was aborted: Could 
not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5104] Entering HttpWebRequest#13834363::Abort()
System.Net Error: 0 : [5104] Exception in HttpWebRequest#13834363:: - The 
request was aborted: The request was canceled..
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5104] Exiting HttpWebRequest#13834363::Abort()
```

Comment: IIS can simply have no access to that certificate.

Comment: I've given permissions to IIS_IUSRS to access that certificate ?

Comment: Setting permissions might be useless, if the certificate is in your account's store, as IIS can only access the machine's stores.

Comment: the certificate is in the machines store. I collect the certificate with StoreLocation.LocalMachine before the tls connection is attempted.

Comment: it was a permissions issue in the end. To fix it I added the cert to the personal store of a local user I created and gave it the permissions. Then I set the app pool identity to this user and it resolved my issue.